# Original reference for 'The essence of all religions is love, compassion and tolerance' by the HH the Dalai Lama

Tags: reference-request, compassion, dalai-lama, religion

Friends,

Does anyone know of the original reference for the saying attributed to His Holiness the Dalai Lama that starts *'The Essence of all religions is love, compasion and tolerance. Kindness is my true religion.'*   I would be grateful if the reference includes the translator.

As a personal note, as a Christian, I find ths very close to the truth.  I expect you know that Jesus said: 'The first commandment is this: Love the Lord your God with all your heart ... the second is 'Love your neighbour as yourself.'  All the law and the prophets hang on these two laws.'

Thanks in anticipation,

Richard

Answer (score 2):

The phrase appears verbatim in [Handbook for the Spirit](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1577316134), in the first essay (the opening chapter) which is titled "Love, Compassion, and Tolerance".

The author of that essay is given as (and copyright is attributed to) His Holiness the Dalai Lama, without any translator.

A copy of that essay can be found here: http://www.ofspirit.com/dalailama1.htm